# Is $\sin(n^k) ≠ (\sin n)^k$ in general?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

Is it true that $\sin(n^k) ≠ (\sin n)^k$ for any positive integers $n$ and integers $k ≠ 1$?

What if $n > 0, k ≠ 1$ are rational?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $\sin(n^k)=\sin(n)^k$, then $\frac{e^{in^k}-e^{-in^k}}{2i}=(\frac{e^{in}-e^{-in}}{2i})^k$, so that $e^i$ would be algebraic.

But that directly contradicts the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) because $i$ is algebraic.