# Show that there is no polynomial P(x) of degree 998 with real coefficients satisfying the equation $P(x)^2 - 1 = P(x^2 + 1)$ for all real numbers x.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, proof-explanation

A friend of mine explained this solution to me but there are a few parts which I still don't understand. Her solution is as follows:

By substituting in $x$ and $-x$ into the equation given, it can be seen that $P(x)^2 - 1 = P(x^2 + 1) = P((-x)^2 + 1) = P(-x)^2 - 1$, and so it is implied that $P(x) = P(-x)$ or $-P(-x)$. Assume there is a contradiction and there is a polynomial of degree 998 satisfying the equation, then $P(x)$ has an even degree of 998 and so it must also be an even polynomial (1. Why is this the case?), that is $P(x)=Q(x^2)$ for some polynomial Q with degree 499.

By setting $x^2=y$ and using the definition of the polynomial Q, it can be seen that for $y \geq 0$, $Q(y)^2 -1 = Q(y^2 + 2y +1)$. By substituting $y$ and $-2-y$ (2. Why these two?), we get $Q(y) = Q(-2-y)$ or $-Q(-2-y)$.

Now set $R(y) = Q(y-1)$ (3. Why?), then since R has an odd degree of 499 (4. Why?) it can only be an odd function so $R(y)=-R(-y)$. By substituting in $y=0$, this gives $R(0) = -R(0)$ and so $R(0)=0$. Therefore $Q(-1)=0$. Computing values of Q for 1, 4, 25, etc. we get $Q(1)=-1, Q(4)=0, Q(25)=-1,...$ (5. How do we get these?) and so Q has infinitely many zeros which is a contradiction.

Any help explaining the 5 questions inset into this solution will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: (1) If the polynomial satisfies $P(-x)=-P(x)$ for infinitely many values of $x$, then it satisfies it for all $x$. If it does, then $P(x)=\frac{P(x)+P(-x)}{2}+\frac{P(x)-P(-x)}{2}=\frac{P(x)-P(-x)}{2}$. But the polynomial $\frac{P(x)-P(-x)}{2}$ has only terms of odd degree, because terms of even degree cancel out. So, $P$ wouldn't have a term of degree $998$. Therefore, it must happen that $P(-x)=P(x)$ for infinitely many values of $x$, and therefore for all $x$.

Comment: (2) $y^2+2y+1=(y+1)^2$. This takes the same values at points that are symmetric with respect to $-1$. The values $y$ and $-2-y$ are (any) two such values. So, $(y+1)^2=((-2-y)+1)^2$, which gives them $Q((y+1)^2)=Q(((-2-y)+1)^2)$.

Comment: According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/polynomials-which-satisfy-p2x-1-px21 there are no non-linear polynomial solutions at all.

Comment: (3) Renaming things are never strictly necessary. But in the previous step they say that $Q(y)=Q(-2-y)$ (or the other case), so $Q$ is symmetric (or antisymmetric) with respect to $-1$. So, $R(y)$ is one that is symmetric (or antisymmetric) with respect to zero. In other words an even or odd polynomial. The new name $R$ is for convenience, just like the new name $y$ is also for convenience.

Comment: (4) $Q$ had degree $499$. So, if $R(y)=Q(y-1)$, then $R$ has the same degree. You didn't ask, but in the next sentence $R(y)=R(-y)$ is just the equation $Q(y)=Q(-2-y)$, and the equation $R(y)=-R(-y)$ is the equation $Q(y)=-Q(-2-y)$.

Comment: (5) $Q(-1)$ comes from $R(0)=0$. The other values come from $Q(y)^2-1=Q(y^2+2y+1)$.

Comment: The only polynomial satisfying this relationship is $p_0 = \frac 12(1\pm\sqrt 5)$

Answer (score 1):

1. For any polynomial $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ with $a_n\ne 0$, the leading term $a_nx^n$  dominates as $|x|\to\infty$. In particular, $P(x)$ and $P(-x)$ have the same sign for $|x|\gg0$ if $n$ is even. Hence at least for $|x|\gg0$, we can only have $P(x)=P(-x)$ and not $P(x)=-P(-x)$. But that means that the polynomials $P(x)$ and $P(-x)$ agree in infinitely many points. This is only possible if they are completely equal, i.e., $P(x)=P(-x)$ for all $x$.
2. Because they work. Perhaps it is easier to see once you notice that $y^2+2y+1=(y+1)^2$. So if we write $z$ for $y+1$, we have $Q(z-1)^2-1=Q(z^2)$. The right hand side is the same for $-z$ as is for $z$, hence $Q(-z-1)^2-1=Q((-z)^2)=Q(z^2)=Q(z-1)^2-1$ and so $Q(-z-1)=\pm Q(z-1)$. Translating back, this says $Q(-y-2)=\pm Q(y)$.
3. I think it was already visible in my answer to $2$, that $z$ is "nicer" than $y$. In $Q(-z-1)=\pm Q(z-1)$, we can get rid of the $-1$ precisely by considering $R(z):=Q(z-1)$ and thereby obtain $R(-z)=\pm R(z)$.
4. As $R(x)=Q(x-1)$, we have $\deg R=\deg Q$. As $P(x)=Q(x^2)$, we have $\deg P=2\deg Q$.
5. If we know $Q(y)$, we also know $Q((y+1)^2)=Q(y)^2-1$. So from $Q(-1)=R(0)=0$, $Q(0)=Q(-1)^2-1=-1$, $Q(1)=Q(0)^2-1=0$, $Q(4)=Q(1)^2-1=-1$, and so on. More formally, we can show by induction that $Q((2k-1)^2)=0$ for all $k$.

Comment: My edit was for a trivial typo at the end of the 1st paragraph.